# Sprite animation cocos2d

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, cocos2d-iphone

How can I animate this sprite?

```
if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:@"Boss_ship_5.png" world:world shapeName:@"Boss_ship" maxHp:50 healthBarType:HealthBarTypeRed])) {
```

I'm trying with this, but with _layer doesn't work...

```
CCSpriteFrameCache * cache =
[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animation];

[animation addSpriteFrame:
    [cache spriteFrameByName:@"Boss_ship_5.png"]];

[animation addSpriteFrame:
    [cache spriteFrameByName:@"Boss_ship_4.png"]];
animation.delayPerUnit = 0.05;

[_layer runAction:
    [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
        [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding sprites to `animation` object, you'll need to load the textures into the `CCSpriteFrameCache`. Please, take a look at

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/633

Also, `CCAnimation` actions are supposed to be used with `CCSprites`. Which class is `_layer` object?

Comment: Bossship2 is an implementation 
@implementation BossShip2 {
ActionLayer * _layer;

And i want animate the Boss_ship sprite, i've just used the method that i post on, but whit a gameobjet*ship.